# Error when importing XML - XMLGetString::pserr: MalformedURLException

Tags: import, xml

I am getting the following error when trying to import XML:

```
text = URLFetch[
   "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=protein&id=8&retmode=xml"];

ImportString[text, {"XML", "XMLObject"}];
```

> XML`Parser`XMLGetString::prserr: MalformedURLException: The URL used an unsupported protocol at Line: 2 Character: 106. >>

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I receive no errors and your code works fine on my computer (MMA 10.2, Win7-64). If the problem persists on your end, you could also try using `Import` directly: `Import["http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=protein&id=8&rettype=xml", "XML"]` which seems to produce the same results.

Comment: Thanks Marco.  It's strange, I am getting the same error.  I actually made a little mistake in what I copy/pasted to you, it should be retmode instead of rettype:  In[171]:= Import["http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=protein&id=8&retmode=xml","XML"]
During evaluation of In[171]:= XML`Parser`XMLGet::prserr: MalformedURLException: The URL used an unsupported protocol at Line: 2 Character: 99 in /var/folders/ll/cl5jhpqx40s__jv4_blwsq5h0000gn/T/m000009227691/efetch.fcgi. >>
During evaluation of In[171]:= Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as XML format. >>

Answer (score 1):

This response is very late, but I had the same problem and I found a solution that might work for you as well.

My XML file had headers that looked like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE {some string} SYSTEM {some other string}>
```

Deleting those headers and then using Import[file] without any extra options correctly imported the XML file.